# How can I make a 24 hour clock with no time.h included?

Tags: c, datetime, timer, mplab, teraterm

I’m creating a C project in MPlab version 8.92 with the goal of creating a 24 hour clock that can also track days, months, and years. I’m not supposed to use the time.h function though. The information is to be displayed via Tera Term. Here’s the code I have so far.

```
#include <xc.h>
#include <pic16f917.h>
#define _XTAL_FREQ 8000000

// BEGIN CONFIG
#pragma config FOSC = HS    // Oscillator Selection bits (HS oscillator)
#pragma config WDTE = OFF   // Watchdog Timer Enable bit (WDT enabled)
#pragma config PWRTE = OFF  // Power-up Timer Enable bit (PWRT disabled)
#pragma config BOREN = ON   // Brown-out Reset Enable bit (BOR enabled)

int main(void)
{
int sec=0,min=0,hour=0;

  while(1)
  {
    __delay_us(1000); 
    sec++;
        if(sec==60)
        {
            sec=0;
            min++;
        } 
            if(min==60)
            { 
                min=0; 
                hour++;
            }  
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: what does "track days, months, and years" mean? If you start at zero time each time your program is run, I doubt anyone is going to be patient enough to wait months and years. Also, I'm assuming `__delay_us` is a delay in microseconds, so you'll need to sleep for 1000000 before incrementing `sec`. But the logic for seconds, minutes, and hours looks good to me. Keep it going with days, months, and years. Of course, things will get more complicated since all months aren't the same number of days, and there are leap years.

Comment: The clock will probably be more accurate if you base it on your own timer handling than calling a delay function (a one second software delay is generally seen as poor implementation).

Comment: You had to use a timer, otherwise you have got an error of the executing time of your mainloop.